# Value returned by sizeof operator in case of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Let's say we have an integer array of size 5 and an int takes 4 bytes of memory.

```
int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
cout<<sizeof(arr);
```

it basically prints 20. If arr points to base address of array. Shouldn't it output p where p is the size of a pointer variable then?

Comment: No. Arrays don't decay to a pointer when used with the `sizeof` operator. It is the total size of the array.

Comment: `sizeof()` always yields the number of bytes used for a variable. Arrays aren't pointers and vice versa.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. Arrays *decay to* pointers in a lot of situations, which confuses people. But if a function (or operator, in the case of `sizeof`) takes an array, then no decay occurs.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not saying that arrays are pointers or anything like that. Just saying that arr here would be containing base address of array i.e arr = &arr[0].

Comment: @AbhishekSharma No, arrays contain the data. An array variable named `arr` does not contain the address of the first element. However it decays to that in some contexts. Not all.

Comment: The best thing you can do is stop using C-style arrays. Use `std::array arr{1,2,3,4,5};` and `arr.size()`.

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` is exactly the same as `sizeof(int[5])`.

Comment: Try not to use "C" style arrays, they are hard to use correctly. Specialy with new/delete. So yes use std::array that at least behaves as any other C++ class (so the rules of passing by reference, const reference also apply directly). If your array can change size at runtime use std::vector. Also avoid the use of new/delete if you can, and if you must allocate memory dynamically use std::make_unique or std::make_shared (regardless of what your current book/teacher says).

Comment: `arr` is **the name of an array**. Its size is the size of the array. In most contexts, the name of an array **decays** into a pointer to its first element, but there are cases, like this one, where that does not happen.

Answer (score 2):

As described here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

sizeof - Queries size of the object or type.

Therefore you have received correctly the size of your table.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeOf()` always returns the total number of bytes occupied in memory.

> When the sizeof operator is applied to an array, it yields the total
> number of bytes in that array, not the size of the pointer represented
> by the array identifier.
> [read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/sizeof-operator?view=msvc-170)

You can still get the size/length of the array by dividing the total number of bytes the whole array occupying by the total number of bytes a single element occupying.

```
int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]
```

Comment: Nowadays you can use `std::size(array)` to get the number of elements in an array.